# can't authorize bearer jwt while sending token via header in Expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, bearer-token, express-jwt

I am trying to authorize logged-in user from it's token sent through header through header.

but after I generated token ,I copied it in header , and sent using `postman`, but everytime it gave me `Unauthorized` response though Token is generated just now and it's expiration time is half hour.

created [token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRil4.png) by login and post request

`Unauthorized` error after sending through [header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utj6q.png)

I am sending `get` request to localhost and adding token in header.

```
router.get(
  "/current",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.user);
  }
);
```

server.js is main file contains

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");

const users = require("./routes/api/users");
const profile = require("./routes/api/profile");
const posts = require("./routes/api/posts");

const app = express();

// Body parser middleware to send input data to backend.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// configure database
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// connect to database
//  if connected successfully  then returns promise by "then()"
// if error then catch error and do "anyFunction()" eg.output that error.

mongoose
  .connect(
    db,
    { useNewUrlParser: true } // added this flag to remove deprecation warning
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("MongoDB connected");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Error occured.\n" + err);
  });

// app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("app.get is working"));
// Passport middleware after connect and before using routes
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Passport Config file call function and pass argument as function() passport
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// Use following routes from apis imported.
app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use("/api/profile", profile);
app.use("/api/posts", posts);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running at port no ${port}`));
```

my `passport.js` file contains

```
const JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require("passport-jwt").ExtractJwt;

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = mongoose.model("users");
// in User.js model file it contains mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

const keys = require("../config/keys");

const opts = {}; // options

opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = keys.secretOrKey;

module.exports = passport => {
  passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {


      User.findById(jwt_payload.id)
        .then(user => {
          if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
          }
          return done(null, false);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log("Error in findById\n " + err));
    })
  );
};
```

router file user.js contains

```
// users.js for authentication and authorization

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const gravatar = require("gravatar");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const keys = require("../../config/keys");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const passport = require("passport");

// Load User Model to check existing email is used for registration or not?
const User = require("../../models/User");

// @route       GET request to api/users/test
// @description Tests users route
// @access      Public, without login
router.get("/test", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: "Users Works" }));

// @route       GET request to api/users/register
// @description new registration of user.
// @access      Public, without login first register

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ email: "Email value exists already." });
    } else {
      console.log("no user found of this email in DB");
      const avatar = gravatar.url(req.body.email, {
        s: "200", //Size of gravatar in pixels
        r: "pg", //rating,
        d: "mm" //default value= 'mm'
      });
      // create user
      const newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        avatar,
        password: req.body.password
      });

      // gensalt(noOfSalts_of_Iterations,(err,salt_result)=>{})
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        // hash(plaintext,salt,callback(err,resultant ciphertext))
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error in bcrypt.hash()");
            throw err;
          }
          //assign salted hash to password
          newUser.password = hash;

          // Save new password in datebase, overriding plaintext;
          newUser
            .save()
            .then(user => res.json(user)) // if yes,then send it as argument in brackets.
            .catch(err =>
              console.log("Error occured in saving hash password in DB\n")
            );
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

// @route       GET request to api/users/login
// @description Login/signing-in registered user. return JWT token
// @access      Public

router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  // find user to match it's password
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    //check if no user
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ email: "User's email   found." });
    }

    // else if do this..

    // if user's email-id is found then match it's password-hash with local-database
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(isMatch => {
      if (isMatch) {
        // user pswd matched => then return JWT token back for authentication
        // res.json({ msg: "Success" });
        const payload = { it: user.id, name: user.name, avatar: user.avatar };

        // created JWT token
        // now sign token
        // jwt.sign(payload, secretKey, expire-time, callback );

        // jwt.sign

        jwt.sign(
          payload,
          keys.secretOrKey,
          { expiresIn: 3600 },
          (err, token) => {
            res.json({
              success: true,
              token: "Bearer " + token
            });
          }
        );
      } else {
        // pswd doesn't matched
        return res.status(400).json({ password: "Password didn't match" });
      }
    });
  });
});

// @route       GET request to api/users/current  - current user with token
// @description Return current user
// @access      Private, can't go without login

router.get(
  "/current",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.json({ msg: "Success" });
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

there is no error in console and servers runs continuously, but it can't verify using token sent in header.

I have generated token after login.

[github link](https://github.com/ganeshdeshmukh1612/connect-geeks) to code

package.json is

```
{
  "name": "find-geeks",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "social media for developers, quite same as Linkedin.",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "gravatar": "^1.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.12",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^9.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think "Bearer" in Authorization header should be specified with uppercase.

Comment: I tried that also, and `JWT` inplace of `bearer`, as well. none of them is working. @AndreiRosu.

Comment: @coderofsiliconvalley, if you have not gotten an answer I dont know what hope there is for me. I am in the same boat as you. Have you resolved this yet?